# SQL group by foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table `Channel` where I have all the available channels and another table `Channel_availableSpecs` where I link the channel id to the specs id. I have done an `inner join` to get the channel name.

What I need to do is based on a `checkedlistbox` in C# **I want to populate a list** of all the available channels that has the selected specs.

I wrote the following query in SQL and it worked but it displayed all the records if they satisfy the condition so I have for example `channel one`  four times because it has the specs 1, 2, 4 and 5.

```
select c.Name
from [dbo].[Channel_availableSpecs] asp
inner join [dbo].[Channel] c on asp.Channel_Id = c.ID 
where asp.ChennelSpec_Id IN ('1' , '2','4' ,'5')
```

So I am trying to group them by channel `id` to be able to view the channel once so I tried while convinced that it won't work.

```
select c.Name
from [dbo].[Channel_availableSpecs] asp
inner join [dbo].[Channel] c on asp.Channel_Id = c.ID 
where asp.ChennelSpec_Id IN ('1' , '2','4' ,'5') Group by asp.Channel_Id
```

Could you help fixing it and how to handle a dynamic list of  specs ids (instead of 1,2,4 and 5) to make the condition on.

Thanks!

Comment: GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved, how come?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: if you are using `GROUP BY` clause in your `SELECT` query, then you can only select those COLUMNS which are present in `GROUP BY` clause .. to get other columns, either you need to use AGGREGATE or GROUP functions on columns .. so in your query, to get the name, you can use `MAX(c.NAME)` ..

Comment: also no need of this condition `asp.ChennelSpec_Id IN ('1' , '2','4' ,'5')` in your WHERE clause .. because based on your JOIN condition, all the SPECS will get selected . so no need to exclusively specify these in WHERE condition

Comment: Can't you solve this by using `DISTINCT`?  `SELECT DISTINCT c.name...`

Comment: I have specified that channel 1 has specs 1,2,4 and 5 and channel 2 has 1,2,4,5 and 6 so i get channel 1 four times and channel 2 four times too. I just need every record once.

Comment: @ihm017 thank you for your comment DISTINCT  fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using subqueries
https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-subqueries/

```
select subqueryResult.Name from 
(
select c.Name, asp.Channel_Id
    from [dbo].[Channel_availableSpecs] asp
    inner join [dbo].[Channel] c on asp.Channel_Id = c.ID 
    where asp.ChennelSpec_Id IN ('1' , '2','4' ,'5') 
) 
as subqueryResult
group by subqueryResult.Channel_Id
```